# FOL - Checking first order entailment with a tool

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is about first order logic.

There are some properties of a knowledge base that are stated in terms of semantic entailment (e.g., KB |= A).

To use a tool to show A is entailed by KB, I think one option is to use some Theorem prover which could give me the result that (KB|- A), assuming the procedure used by theorem prover is sound.

Supposing the procedure used by theorem prover is not complete, that means I may not be able to reach the conclusion that A is entailed by KB.

Could you please assist with these questions:

1- Are there any other options (other than theorem prover tool) to automatically find out if A is entailed by KB?

2- In case I am using a theorem prover with sound procedure, and I am not able to reach a conclusion, is there anything I can do (perhaps manually?) to get to that prove?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The issue is that FOL is not *decidable*; so, we can use sound and complete proof procedures, like e.g. tableaux and resolution, but - in principle - we have no way to know in advance if a certain formula is valid (and thus has a proof).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I think FOL is semi-decidable; if KB |= A we could find that but if not, the procedure may go on forever. However, my question was in regards with the case that KB |= A, but since we have a sound procedure, we may not get it, and we need to use other methods perhaps

Comment: If we have $KB \vDash A$, by *completeness* we know that $KB \vdash A$. Thus, it is enough to apply e.g. Resolution proof procedure to$\{ KB \} \cup \{ \lnot A \}$ and the procedure will give us the requested proof.